# Buffering unique values from a stream until it is not unique anymore - using cache inside groupby

Tags: java, project-reactor

I have a flux from a kafka topic. So I have to deal with large infinite hot source. For simplicity stake though, I am going to assimilate it with a Flux of Integers.

I want to turn this flux into an unordered flux of values that contains only values not unique to the flux.

For instance `1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 4 -> 2, 2, 1, 1, 1`

Here is an attempt that works:

```
    Flux<Integer> flux = Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4);

    flux.groupBy(Function.identity())
        .flatMap(
                it -> {
                    Flux<Integer> shared = it.cache();
                    return Flux.concat(shared.buffer(2)
                            .take(1)
                            .map(buff -> buff.stream().findFirst().get()), shared.skip(1));
                }
        )
        .doOnNext(System.out::println)
        .blockLast();
```

However I don't like the use of Flux.cache inside the flatMap, as I am worried about memory usage.

I am also not sure on how it would work with a hot source, as if I use publish() to turn into a hot flux, nothing happens.

I already explained everything earlier.

Comment: Can't quite understand your problem. If your source is infinite, does it means you need to keep track of ALL elements appeared? So you can find values not unique.

Comment: Vinz243 is right. I'm just guessing here but if you want to handle duplicate incoming msg, it'd be better to guard it at the point you do map(process(message)), where you can implement a cache with a combination of things inside the message you identify as keys - identify the same task/content. Typically one could use a Map with eviction strategies like https://guava.dev/releases/9.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html(or use Redis if distributed).

Comment: @samabcde my goal is to keep track of each first unique integer received, until I receive a second equal value

Comment: @HoaPhan that's a good idea thanks, but how do I handle the first message? I still want it sent down the pipeline, once I received another matching message

Comment: @Viz234, you just described it. Just make the computer do exactly that.
map(msg -> process(msg)).map(//send it somewhere else)
where  process(msg) is idempotent.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood the requirements, you want to

- filter duplicates
- from a real-time stream.

To filter duplicates, it is crucial to decide what is a duplicate (fast and safe!). The rest can be handled in a reactive manner like this:

```java
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

import org.reactivestreams.Publisher;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

@Slf4j
public class ReactiveDemo {

    // here we "simulate" very fast "indexer"
    static final Set<Integer> uniques = new HashSet<>();
    // to recognize past dups, we need:
    static final Set<Integer> dupes = new HashSet<>();
    // for "memory" these datastructures are efficient, in "real world"/on large scale/distributed, we might have other ..

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Flux<Integer> tstInbound = Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4);
        // for endless simulation, replace with:
        // Flux.from(source);// kill with Ctrl+C (SIG), sry

        // subscribe/publish/do something, DONT block!
        tstInbound.subscribe((nxt) -> {
            // here is the main job/business logic
            // do it as good, fast, ... as possible
            if (uniques.contains(nxt)) {// we have a (1st time) duplication

                uniques.remove(nxt);
                dupes.add(nxt);

                // we did our job (identifying, handling, memorizing a dup), bye:
                downStream.accept(nxt); // down stream can be slow, we "fire (& forget)"
            } else if (dupes.contains(nxt)) {// we have a (repeated) duplicate
                // bye:
                downStream.accept(nxt); // ... we don't halt here
            } else { // first time encounter
                // don't send to donwstream, but safe "uniqe"
                uniques.add(nxt);
            }
        });
        // nxt level: caching/buffering/throtelling/draining :)
    }

    // smaller KEY_SPACE -> more and faster duplicates
    static final Integer KEY_SPACE = Integer.MAX_VALUE / 32 / 8182;
    // (only) test data generator
    static final Random RND = new Random(0xCAFEBABE); // same seed-> same data!
    // this our (test) publisher:
    static Publisher<? extends Integer> source = (s) -> {
        while (true) { // kill with CTRL+C, sowwy! :)
            try {
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(10); // <- little simulate
                s.onNext(RND.nextInt(KEY_SPACE)); // <- publisher api (1.)
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                log.warn("Interrupted upstream");
                s.onError(e); // <- publisher api (2.)
            }
            s.onComplete(); // <- publisher api (3.)
        }
    };

    // our down stream, just logs:
    static Consumer<Integer> downStream = (i) -> {
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1); // <- more simulate
            log.info("{}", i);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            log.warn("Interrupted downstream");
        }
    };
}
```

For `Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4);`, we get:

```text
xx:x1:51.028 [main] INFO com.example.demo.ReactiveDemo -- 1
xx:x1:52.042 [main] INFO com.example.demo.ReactiveDemo -- 1
xx:x1:53.055 [main] INFO com.example.demo.ReactiveDemo -- 1
xx:x1:54.062 [main] INFO com.example.demo.ReactiveDemo -- 2
xx:x1:55.073 [main] INFO com.example.demo.ReactiveDemo -- 4
```

The simulation (re-)produces (with `KEY_SPACE` and `0xCAFEBABE`)

```text
xx:x0:11.756 [main] INFO com.example.demo.ReactiveDemo -- 6751
xx:x0:12.941 [main] INFO com.example.demo.ReactiveDemo -- 3948
xx:x0:13.998 [main] INFO com.example.demo.ReactiveDemo -- 838
xx:x0:15.216 [main] INFO com.example.demo.ReactiveDemo -- 3294
xx:x0:16.407 [main] INFO com.example.demo.ReactiveDemo -- 8139
# .. runs "infinitely" :)
```